# How to read users list in slack channels / groups / dm

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I am first time creating an app on slack which responds to command in channel / group / dm. My questions are

- should i use slack bot token or user token , how to decide on it ?
- If i use user token do i need any additional scope access , just to read list of users in group / personal / channel only where i am part of

I want to know what are best practices on that

Answer (score 0):

> should i use slack bot token or user token , how to decide on it ?

When architecting your app, it's best to require the *least number of scopes as required* for your app to function. On the same thread, you should only use the User Token if you have a method that only the user token can access or you want to do something on behalf of the user, otherwise it's best to stick with the bot token only.

> If i use user token do i need any additional scope access , just to read list of users in group / personal / channel only where i am part of

The method to retrieve a list of users is the [`conversations.members`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.members) method. You'll need the specific `*:read` scope for the type of conversation that you want to pull the users from: im, mpim, private channel or public channel.